# How to Scheduled job recognize CDC?

Tags: sql, ssis, cdc

I scheduled a Package From 'SSIS' Catalog by using 'SQL' Server Agent.

I used `Change Data Capture` Task (cdc) in my packages.

When I run job by Right-Clicking on 'Start job at step' cdc works and updates transfer to my Stage,but when job run automatically,job runs but cdc doesn't work it means updates don't transfer to my Stage.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a variety of reasons.

-is it possible the Step is being skipped based on the way the SQL Job is written? (check the On Success property of the previous steps)

-is the job failing due to syntax or permission?  (check the job history)

-put some simple, non-CDC related steps in the SSIS job to see if it is even running the SSIS catalog?